Installation of web2c (binary)
I'm curious about interpreters and compilers and have been using latex for some years for academic stuff.
I thought that it would be interesting to see how tex or pdftex works.
Knowing only C, I want to convert tex.web to C code with web2c.
I downloaded the texlive source from : svn checkout svn://tug.org/texlive/branches/branch2024/Build. Next I created a simple directory to build the source with : /path/to/texlive-source/configure --prefix=/usr/local/texlive/2024.
After that I did make && sudo make install && make check with no errors.
(Had already sudo apt install texinfo)
I did also add /usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu to my path.

There is a web2c binary in the build directory at /texlive-build/texk/web2c/web2c but why didn't it get installed in /usr/local/texlive/2024 ? Have I missed a configuration option ?
Installation section on tug.org web2c tells us that "Installing Web2c is mostly the same as installing any other Kpathsea-using program." with a link to a section that don't seem to exist anymore.

I have spend hours reading the docs but don't get anywhere. I would gladly appreciate to get some indications :)

I didn’t reboot but I resourced the file. (source ~/.profile)

/usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu is not a standard TeX Live path. What is in /usr/local/texlive/2024/?

I don't have an answer for you right now, but the last couple of times I installed TeX Live from source, I was able to use most of the programs from the directory they were built in (indeed looked like something something x86_64-pc-linux-gnu), even without anything getting installed to /usr/local/texlive/2024.

@cfr I have the follwing files in /usr/local/texlive/2024/: applcations, bin, include, lib and texmf-dist.

@ShreevatsaR Do you know if web2c did work correctly for you in the build directory ?

Yes I remember following the web2c instructions and the binaries working. I didn't even specify --prefix=; I just built everything into the default directory (I think it's called Build or Master or Work or something; I forget the details; it was a couple of years ago) and they just worked from there.

BTW if you don't get answers here you can also consider the mailing list. [Sorry I don't have the time right now to try it out myself and help you; just leaving these comments because I felt bad no one was helping you :)]

@ShreevatsaR I will eventually consider the mailing list. And no worries! I appreciate the time and effort you already have put in to help me :)
